# is there a way to print a string in the path of the file that i want to include in jsp?

Tags: jsp, include

```
<% String path = "MyPath"; %>
<jsp:include  page='iWantToPrintpathHere.jsp' />
```

I have tried `<jsp:include  page='${path}.jsp' />` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Your first line of code,

```
<% String path = "MyPath"; %>
```

creates a scripting variable. Therefore, you must use a JSP expression to access it.

```
<jsp:include  page='<%=path%>' />
```

This assumes that the variable MyPath is a path relative to your webapp.

${path} refers to a scoped variable.